# How do you edit videos to slide on and off the screen?

Tags: video, editing, premiere-elements

Hi I’m trying to edit a group of videos so that they continuously slide on and off the screen. I was wondering if there was a faster way to do this instead of individually adjusting the position key frames of all my videos.

The type of motion I’m referring to is like 1:51 of this YouTube video

Thanks and any help would be appreciated!